# Was Sukuna always stronger than Satoru Gojo, or became stronger and at some point surpassed him?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In the Jujutsu Kaisen wikia it states that

> Sukuna killed Satoru Gojo

Was Sukuna always stronger than Satoru Gojo, or became stronger and at some point surpassed him?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, given that Sukuna is millenia-old sorcerer, it's more likely that Gojo (presumably) had suprassed him at some point.

Re you question: according to the last panel of 235, Gojo indeed was stronger than Sukuna (i.e. practically incapacitating him from further battle) until Gege pulled a `deus ex machina` and gave Sukuna a plot power of "cutting infinity".

Even if we omit this controversial point, Sukuna heavily relying on Mahoraga's powers as a single option to counter Gojo's Infinity is a good indication that Sukuna did actually only surpass Gojo after transferring himself to Megumi and inheriting his technique.